Large fishtank weight concern
I got given a 130gallon fish tank and I want to make sure the floor can support it. It's a large 72x18x57 inch tank and as best as I can see, I have placed it against an external wall and over 4 floor joists that are 6x1.5 inch. Directly in front of the basement concrete wall there seems to be a studded wall too as part of the basement finish. So the weight including stand and water will be about 3000 lbs. Should I have concern?

Type of stand?  Does it have legs or a solid base speading the weight over the base area?

130 litres is about 34 gallons (in US) or 29 gallons in imperial. At 6ft long it won't be too deep or wide...

Those joists are very small by modern standards. Please revise to tell us how far they span. Note that the framed basement wall is not load-bearing, strictly speaking.

Comment: "It's 320 us gallons" Question says: "a 130gallon fish tank" So is it 130 or 320? Please proofread your question and edits. This will help you get a good answer. (320 gallons = 73920 cubic inches, close enough to 73872, so maybe it is 320?)
